# Get Public Key from CSR

Tags: powershell, pki

Can someone please help me with the following question (using PowerShell)

I have a CSR in Base64 string saved to a variable called $CSR

I want to get the public key from the CSR, the reason I want to do this is I want to check the public key (and therefore the private key) is not being reused when submitting a CSR for a Microsoft CA. My idea is to basically get a copy of the cert with the same subject name (if one exists) from the CA and check its public key again the CSR.

So I need to get the public key from the CSR as mentioned, so this far I have done the following

`$RequestX = New-Object ComObjectX509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10`
$RequestX.InitializeDecode($CSR,6)
`$RequestX.PublicKey

rather than the Public key itself being returned I get a com object. Will I have to use reflection on this com object to extract the public key?
Is there an easier way? (I could use certutil and a bit of regex but would rather not)

Thanks all
E Brant

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out my messing about etc....

So the goal was to compare the public key in a CSR to the public key in an existing certificate to see if they match of not (now may be a much easier way, but this is now I got it)

```
$CSR = @"
<CSR here in base64>
"@

$ObjXX = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile("C:\CSR\Cert-TestSite.cer")

$X = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ObjXX.GetPublicKey())

$RequestX = New-Object -ComObject X509enrollment.CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 

$RequestX.InitializeDecode($CSR,6)

$Y = $RequestX.PublicKey.EncodedKey() -replace "`r`n"

Compare-Object $X $Y
```